# HttpContext cancels text in label

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have simple btnPullDataIntoCsv_Click method in my ASP.NET app which prints something into label, downloads data from SQL Server table and push into csv such like that:

```
protected void btnPullDataIntoCsv_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        lblUserMessage.Text = String.Empty;
        PullData p = new PullData();

        // Print something into label
        lblUserMessage.Text = "I'm printing text into label.";
        lblUserMessage.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
        lblUserMessage.Font.Bold = true;

        // pull the data from sql table into csv
        p.pullDataIntoCsv(start, stop);
    }
```

pullDataIntoCsv method inside PullData class simply downloads data from SQL Server table and push the data into csv.

```
public void pullDataIntoCsv()
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
            {
                SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(@"select * from someTable", con);
                da.Fill(dt);

                string[] columnNames = dt.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>().
                                                  Select(column => column.ColumnName).
                                                  ToArray();
                sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", columnNames));

                foreach (DataRow row in dt.Rows)
                {
                    string[] fields = row.ItemArray.Select(field => field.ToString()).
                                                    ToArray();
                    sb.AppendLine(string.Join(",", fields));
                }

                HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;

                context.Response.Write(sb.ToString());
                context.Response.ContentType = "text/csv";
                context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=someData.csv");
                context.Response.End();
            }
        }
```

Not sure why but I cannot see text in label when I trigger btnPullDataIntoCsv_Click method. I'm very new in this so could you please, give me a hint what I'm doing wrong or what I'm missing in my code?

Comment: `lblUserMessage.Text` <= this is an update to the UI which would need to be pushed back to the client in the traditional POST request. In your method you do something else, the code downloads to the Response stream and then calls `context.Response.End();`. You can't mix those 2 things. Either send the updated values in the traditional form POST request and update the UI on the client OR execute a download and do not update the UI from the post request. A solution here could be to use javascript to clear the text box and also use it to start the download.

Comment: How can I avoid of blocking UI thread in my pulldataintocsv method?

Comment: @CodeCaster in this case I think Igor's interpretation is more accurate. This code will never update the UI because the response is turned into a file download.

Comment: @martinkabe I don't think blocking is the issue. Igor's comment is correct.

Comment: Sorry, I'm very new in this to resolve based on @Igor comment. I'm only wondering about splitting both parts into independent _click events but this is not what I'm trying to achieve. Is there anything very simple I can add/remove into/from my code to solve this issue?

Comment: With minimal code change the easiest would be to turn  the click event into a download functionality only and then use pure javascript or the jquery library to clear the values of the text boxes on your form.

Comment: @martinkabe the simplest thing is exactly what Igor suggested. You can research how to do both these things using Javascript.

Comment: @ADyson heh, think I missed the ASP.NET part of this question, thanks.

Comment: Thanks @Igor, great suggestion.